# Android Send Imageview Image to Firebase with Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have one ImageButton, 1 ImageView and a Button called submit.
Whenever We click on ImageButton Camera Intent is open and we take a snap then it shows to ImageView. Everything is working till here is fine. So how can I upload this camera Intent image to Firebase with authentication.?
I am not able to find any tutorial video which thought us this

```
package com.example.android.besafe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.storage.StorageManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton mProfileImage;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase;
    private String userID;
    private String mProfileImageUrl;
    private Button confirm;
    private Uri resultUri;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        mProfileImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnselect);
        confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("fbusersinfo").child(userID);

        mProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });

        confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                //saveUserInformation();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
             //Uri imageUri = data.getData();
             //StorageReference filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_images").child(userID);

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            /* resultUri = imageUri;
            mProfileImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
            */
        }
    }

  /*  private void saveUserInformation() {
        if(resultUri != null) {

            StorageReference filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_images").child(userID);

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(data);

            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    Map newImage = new HashMap();
                    newImage.put("profileImageUrl", downloadUrl.toString());
                    mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(newImage);

                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
        else{finish();}

    }  */




}
```

Comment: Can you share code

Comment: @R2R please ignore commented code. I tried to connect is using firebase but so far no luck

Comment: what you mean by authentication? Write and Read to Firebase Storage based on security rules.

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan If user is signed in then he can upload image otherwise not

Comment: Here is the tutorial which will help you : https://theengineerscafe.com/firebase-storage-android-tutorial/. Update the question with your storage rules and the exact error log from the Android studio console.

Comment: If the user is not signed in then firebase will throw error which you can show as a message. I think your main problem is to send image to firebase storage?

Comment: yes Sir  @RahulChandrabhan

Comment: @mark922  in this video he is just uploading image from gallery which is done by me
I am not able to repeat same function with Camera Intent

Comment: Have a look at this and follow Upload from data in memory topic. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files. I believe that you're not able to fetch the data from uri. Try it out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is the Firebase Storage upload method

You have to convert your bitmap to File then you can retrieve URI and pass it to my method

```
 private void uploadMethod() {
        progressDialog();
        FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageReferenceProfilePic = firebaseStorage.getReference();
        StorageReference imageRef = storageReferenceProfilePic.child("Your Path" + "/" + "Image Name" + ".jpg");

        imageRef.putFile(imageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //if the upload is successful
                        //hiding the progress dialog
                        //and displaying a success toast
                        dismissDialog();
                        String profilePicUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        //if the upload is not successful
                        //hiding the progress dialog
                        dismissDialog();
                        //and displaying error message
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.getCause().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //calculating progress percentage
//                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
//                        //displaying percentage in progress dialog
//                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                    }
                });

    }
```

### You can retrieve your image from ImageView Like this

```
public byte[] getByteArray(ImageView imageView){
        // Get the data from an ImageView as bytes
        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        return data;
    }
```

And change my method like this:

```
imageRef.putBytes(getByteArray)
```

Comment: Sir where and how should I call this uploadMethod() ?

Comment: Welcome Ahmed Abbas

Comment: Have you upvoted my answer?  It would be great if you do it